# Why did my table id jump?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a simple Mobile Service that takes in a unique identifier and then either creates a row or updates an existing row in a table with the most recent access of a given row. Up until today, there were XX entries in the list (greater than 10, less than 100). The ID's were incrementing sequentially just fine and there were no errors being thrown for the scripts.

Then, suddenly there was a jump from XX to 100YY, and the last few entries have continued along this index. Near this time, there was an error recorded in the logs - a timeout.

Why did this happen? Why the jump? Is there a way to fix it (especially without wiping the table)? How can I prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 3):

I was linked to a previous entry in the [Azure MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/bbe61888-0b8e-48f4-849c-8b4d35eaf66f/identity-primary-key-field-in-sql-azure-skipping-large-blocks-ids-ints). At the end of the thread was this response:

> Good news (sort of); I talked to somebody at MSFT and he cleared the air a bit. I will share with you what he said:
>
> - The TF 272 option won't work in Azure
> - The behavior (reseed) is by design, but has been acknowledged internally as less than optimal and a request has been made (again, internally) to change the behavior. This may or may not happen.
> - The reseed is triggered by instance bounces, which are covered by the SLA. They are mostly patches to the OS or SQL Azure itself.
>
> The most important point was that, chances are, we will never hit the int limit. I think we all are forgetting (at least I did) that SQLAzure is not like SQL Server; there are very real limits in place, specifically total db size (150 gigs). He also said there is a max row limit per table of 10 million records, but I'm not finding documentation of that on the web. Assuming that is correct, even with jumps of 1000k, we would still be safe. And yes you could also switch to a bigint if you hit the int limit before the total db size limit. His point was simply that we will run out of room before we hit the int limit.
>
> It isn't ideal for sure, but I'm no longer concerned about hitting an int limit.
>
> Hopefully that helps some people here.

The 'reseed' discussed is basically a re-initialization of the 'current id index'. Basically, whenever there's a bounce of the sql response, it will jump a safe distance in order to make sure that there is an id available for it.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` field in the table is created using the IDENTITY property with a (1,1) value for the (seed, increment) pair - you can check that by opening the database used by your mobile service in SQL Server Management Studio, selecting the table, right-click it, and select Script Table as --> CREATE To --> New Query Editor Window. So the values should be incremented by one. And by default the IDENTITY_INSERT property is set to OFF (you'll get the error if you try to insert data on the table using the management studio with the identity field set).

The only thing I can think of that may have caused this big jump would be if data was inserted then deleted in the table. If the next value for the `id` would be X, and you insert Y elements and delete them right away, the next value for `id` will be (X + Y), even though all the Y elements have been deleted. Could that have happened in your case?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was linked to what appears to be the answer (an instance bounce likely due to OS or SQL Azure patches).